# C# datagridview argument out of range exception

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a datagridview and I am trying to add a new row to it.
It has 3 columns, 0 = image, 1 = text, 2 = text.

It adds the first row fine, but when I click again to add the second row it throws the exception.

```
        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
        row.Cells[1].Value = message; //specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
        row.Cells[2].Value = response;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add *columns* to `DataGridViewRow`:

```
  ...
  // At least 3 columns required: Cells[] is a zero based collection
  row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()); // <- Ckeck cell actual type
  row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()); // <- Ckeck cell actual type
  row.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell()); // <- Ckeck cell actual type

  row.Cells[1].Value = message; // OK
  row.Cells[2].Value = response;
```

A better way to start from existing `dataGridView`:

```
  DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView.Rows[dataGridView.Rows.Add()];

  row.Cells[1].Value = message; 
  row.Cells[2].Value = response;
```

Answer (score 0):

//Try This :
dataGridView.Rows.Add(null,message,response)